# One To Many field does not update in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
public class Conference {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "host_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private User host;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "PARTICIPANT_CONFERENCE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CONFERENCE_ID_FRK"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PARTICIPANT_ID_FRK")
    )
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<User> participants;
}

@Entity
public class User {
    @ManyToMany(
            targetEntity = Conference.class,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,
            mappedBy = "participants"
    )
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Conference> conferenceSet;

    @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = Conference.class,
            mappedBy = "host",
            cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Conference> conferenceHostSet;
}
```

I used JPA and have a problem that OneTOMany field does not update in JPA.

If I added host in Conference, but User's host set did not update.

So, I tried to update User's host set, too.

```
Set<Conference> conferences = form.getHost().getConferenceHostSet();
conferences.add(conference);
userRepository.save(form.getHost().setConferenceSet(conferences));
```

It works well, but User's participant set also updated.

How can I update only host?

Comment: Can you post the `save()` too? And how do you create `Conference`?

Comment: @ujulu, Sure, it works only each side, Conference. If I save Conference, Conference's host is updated. But User's host set is not updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set cascading to only work for "remove" you need to set it up for all of the actions you want.

Comment: Thank you to reply, I try to change User's host set from REMOVE to ALL. But it still does not work. So, I try to set Conference's host to ALL, but it occur error that is ``org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.pjwards.aide.domain.User``.

Comment: That error is a whole another problem. You receive the detached entity error if you query an object out in one session, then in another session try to use it where it interacts with the database. The other thing I've been burnt before, is make sure you are using the correct annotations. Depending on if you are using the entity manager or not, you may or may not have to use the JPA annotations or the Hibernate annotations.